# PHP Query Data Based on Multiple Select

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple select options.

```
<select name="uid" multiple>
     <option value="001">001</option>
     <option value="002">002</option>
     <option value="003">003</option>
</select>
```

I want to query data in mysql. For ex, If I choose uid 001 & 003, then the data  for uid 001 & 003 will be shown.

```
$get_uid = $_GET['uid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE uid = '$uid'");
```

So how can I set the query for multiple value select.

Comment: look at php's [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and mysql's [`IN()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$get_uid = $_GET['uid']; //array
if (count($get_uid) > 0) {
    $get_uid = implode(',', $get_uid); //string;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE uid IN ($get_uid)");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$get_uid = implode(",",$_GET['uid']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM t_user WHERE uid IN ($get_uid)");
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: Why do you link to a page about MySQL's `IN()`, but use `=` -> `uid = ('$get_uid')`? `'$get_uid'` will cause the value to be a string, not a csv.

Comment: don't forget to sanitize user input

Comment: You still have quotes around `'$get_uid'`, so it will be evaluated as 1 string literal, ie. `('001,003')` instead of individual ints, ie. `(001,003)`